# Cannot find module when attempting to automatically import node.js modules

Tags: node.js, file-io

I have a directory `tmp` that has 3 test node.js modules `[mod0.js, mod1.js, mod2.js]`.

I am attempting to write a function in order to import these three modules into an array and then return said array.  I can drop to REPL and can import each file using `var x = require("./tmp/mod0");` etc without any issue.

When I attempt to run the following function though to automate this, I receive the error `[Error: Cannot fine module './tmp/mod0']`.

```
var _importFiles = function(path, files){
    var moduleList = []
    , trimmedName;

    files.forEach(function (element, index, array){
        if (_fs.lstatSync(path + "/" + element).isFile()){
            trimmedName =  element.substring(0, (element.length - 3));
            moduleList.push(require("./" + path + "/" + trimmedName));
        }
    });

    return moduleList;
};
```

I am passing in `'tmp'` for the `path` parameter and the output of `fs.readdirSync(path)` for the `files` parameter.

If I check `process.cwd();` within the `if` block, it matches that of the REPL console.

I'm trying to figure out why it works when I manually do it in REPL but not automated.

Comment: Try using `path = path.join(__dirname, path)` at the top of your `_importFiles` function to ensure that the passed in `path` is relative to the current directory. Note that `path.join` is a function from Node so you will need to rename your function's `path` argument to prevent a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code slightly to this:

```
var _fs = require('fs');
var path = process.cwd() + '/tmp'

var _importFiles = function(path, files){
    var moduleList = [], trimmedName;

    files.forEach(function (element, index, array){
        if (_fs.lstatSync(path + "/" + element).isFile()){
            trimmedName =  element.substring(0, (element.length - 3));
            moduleList.push(require("./" + path + "/" + trimmedName));
        }
    });

    return moduleList;
};

var imports = _importFiles('./tmp', _fs.readdirSync(path));
console.log(imports);
```

Which gives me:

```
$ node import.js
[ 'imported mod0 automatically', 'imported mod1 automatically' ]
```

The mod files are simple `module.exports = "imported mod(x) automatically";`

So now my return list has an array. Also; Make sure your directory has read permissions (which im sure it does)

Comment: OK, this lead me to the solution.  My issue is a pathing issue.  My import module was looking for the tmp directory relative to the module itself.  Since my tmp directory is in a sibling directory, it failed.  I corrected the pathing issue and it resolved my situation.  Thanks!